# Interactive cursor to know coordinates (latitude and longitude) in boundary layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, shapefile, coordinates, gui

Is there a way of knowing the coordinates in a specific point of a shapefile (boundary layer/map of the country) in QGIS?

Similar to what is done on Google Earth. As the cursor moves, the coordinates are changed at the bottom of the screen

Answer (score 10, accepted):

QGIS already shows the coordinates at the bottom of the screen when the cursor moves.

[image]

See for more details: https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_gui.html#control-the-map-canvas

Comment: Oh... Just to double-check... they are reverse correct? Given in longitude and latitude? Instead of the other way around

Comment: Change the Project CRS (at thebottom right of the QGIS window) to EPSG:4326. OR: Right click everywhere on the map canvas, than you can select the CRS you want and the coordinates for the clicked point will be shown (works since QGIS 3.16)